# Cmake library outdir

Tags: cmake

I cant output my lib to my lib folder , I tried this , and it outputs to lib/debug
but I need  output mylib.lib exactly to ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib

```
add_library(mylib STATIC  ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib   
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) presents you with a possible solution (emphasis mine):

> Multi-configuration generators (Visual Studio, Xcode, Ninja Multi-Config) append a per-configuration subdirectory to the specified directory **unless a generator expression is used.**

You can use a generator expression not changing anything about the value to prevent the config based suffix. You should modify the archive name accordingly to allow for output files of different configurations to coexist in the same directory.

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib$<0:>"
        OUTPUT_NAME "mylib-$<CONFIG>"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  " ${CMAKE__BINARY_DIR}/lib")
```

Comment: There is **variable** [CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) but there is no **property** with given name. So your  `set_target_properties` is meaningless. In any case, setting `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` just causes `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property to be set, and this property is already set in the question post.

Answer (score 0):

In CMake, Visual Studio is a **multiconfiguration** [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html). Such generators have a specific when interpret [ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) property for the target:

> Multi-configuration generators (Visual Studio, Xcode, Ninja Multi-Config) **append a per-configuration subdirectory** to the specified directory unless a generator expression is used.

If you want to use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib` as output directory for the library only for Debug build, and Release build is not interesting for you, then set [ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html) property instead:

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib
)
```

If you want to specify different output directories for Debug and Release builds, then set both properties:

```
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib-release
)
```

Setting the same directory for both Debug and Release builds is discouraged: That way Release build will overwrite library created in Debug and vise versa.

---

Placing build artifacts (e.g. libraries and executables created by the project) in the source directory, as implied by `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib` output directory, is discouraged too.

Usually, build artifacts are placed in the build directory and its descendant directories. So, deleting build directory completely removes the build.

If you want to store some build artifacts for use even when build directory is remove, then **install** those artifacts. CMake provides the functionality for installing libraries, executables and other files.